# HTML table border is now showing in asp.net mvc 3 view

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

So here is the problem illustrated with couple of printscreens for the different attempts I made to solve this problem. All this is happening in ASP.NET MVC 3 View.

I create my table like this :

```
<div id="drawForm">
    <table id="drawTemplate" style="border:1px solid lightgrey;border-collapse: collapse">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Model[i].Columns.Count > 0)
            {
                <tr>
                    @for (var j = 0; j < Model[i].Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Columns[j].RowNumber)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Columns[j].ColumnNumber)
                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Columns[j].QuestionText)
                            @Html.EditorFor(x => x[i].Columns[j].FieldValue)
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
  </div>
```

Notice the styling of the table, when the border is set to 1px I get this :

[image: One Pixel Table Border]

After some search about the topic I found some sort of solution by keeping everything the same only changing the table border value from 1 to 3px. After doing this I get :

[image: Three Pixel Table Border]

Now I can see all the borders and I set the color of the border to red just to be more clear what I am meaning, in fact I can set it to `lightgray` and it's almost acceptable but one - it seems like some sort of a hack by doing this, and also -  don't see something out of the ordinary which don't allow the normal rendering of the table and of course - I would really like to have a normal table layout and not to be forced to change the border width because of that.

I use some styling which is the same for both examples so I left it for the end :

```
#drawForm 
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 690px;
    height: 800px;   
    border: 1px solid black; 

}
#drawTemplate {
    width: 690px;
}
tr 
{
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    }
td {
 border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

So the thing I would like to know is - why I get this problem at first place and of course - is there any way to deal with it besides this trick with the border width?

P.S

HTML output :

```
<table id="drawTemplate" >
                <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input name="[0].Columns[0].RowNumber" type="hidden" value="1" />
                            <input name="[0].Columns[0].ColumnNumber" type="hidden" value="1" />
                            alabala
                            <input class="text-box single-line" name="[0].Columns[0].FieldValue" type="text" value="" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="[0].Columns[1].RowNumber" type="hidden" value="1" />
                            <input name="[0].Columns[1].ColumnNumber" type="hidden" value="2" />

                            <input class="text-box single-line" name="[0].Columns[1].FieldValue" type="text" value="yes" />
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input name="[1].Columns[0].RowNumber" type="hidden" value="2" />
                            <input name="[1].Columns[0].ColumnNumber" type="hidden" value="1" />
                            alabala
                            <input class="text-box single-line" name="[1].Columns[0].FieldValue" type="text" value="yes" />
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input name="[2].Columns[0].RowNumber" type="hidden" value="3" />
                            <input name="[2].Columns[0].ColumnNumber" type="hidden" value="1" />
                            alabala
                            <input class="text-box single-line" name="[2].Columns[0].FieldValue" type="text" value="yes" />
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input name="[3].Columns[0].RowNumber" type="hidden" value="4" />
                            <input name="[3].Columns[0].ColumnNumber" type="hidden" value="1" />
                            alabala
                            <input class="text-box single-line" name="[3].Columns[0].FieldValue" type="text" value="no" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="[3].Columns[1].RowNumber" type="hidden" value="4" />
                            <input name="[3].Columns[1].ColumnNumber" type="hidden" value="2" />
                            alabala
                            <input class="text-box single-line" name="[3].Columns[1].FieldValue" type="text" value="no" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="[3].Columns[2].RowNumber" type="hidden" value="4" />
                            <input name="[3].Columns[2].ColumnNumber" type="hidden" value="3" />
                            alabala
                            <input class="text-box single-line" name="[3].Columns[2].FieldValue" type="text" value="no" />
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input name="[4].Columns[0].RowNumber" type="hidden" value="5" />
                            <input name="[4].Columns[0].ColumnNumber" type="hidden" value="1" />
                            alabala
                            <input class="text-box single-line" name="[4].Columns[0].FieldValue" type="text" value="no" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="[4].Columns[1].RowNumber" type="hidden" value="5" />
                            <input name="[4].Columns[1].ColumnNumber" type="hidden" value="2" />

                            <input class="text-box single-line" name="[4].Columns[1].FieldValue" type="text" value="no" />
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input name="[5].Columns[0].RowNumber" type="hidden" value="6" />
                            <input name="[5].Columns[0].ColumnNumber" type="hidden" value="1" />
                            alabala
                            <input class="text-box single-line" name="[5].Columns[0].FieldValue" type="text" value="" />
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input name="[6].Columns[0].RowNumber" type="hidden" value="7" />
                            <input name="[6].Columns[0].ColumnNumber" type="hidden" value="1" />
                            alabala
                            <input class="text-box single-line" name="[6].Columns[0].FieldValue" type="text" value="no" />
                        </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Are you using the default style or custom css?

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Mozilla, and the only custom CSS is the one I posted.

Comment: Can you post the final html ?

Comment: You can see it now in the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this CSS declaration, it's enough for you to get a border for your table element and for each cell

```
#drawForm table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

#drawForm table, .drawForm table td {
   border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

Also it seems like you'll be having that issue because you are looping through tr and td, where few td's are missed thus messing up your table as you need to declare `rowspan` and `colspan`

Comment: Well, like this I don't get no borders at all.

Comment: @Leron completely sorry, I replaced `.` with `#` now you can try

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I just realized :)

Comment: @Leron You cannot have such table dynamic, unless and until you are looping entire table